# How do I change my app from read only to Read, write and access Direct Messages? twitter API

Tags: api, twitter

I know that it should be in settings, but actually it is not. They changed GUI, as i see. Any ideas?

Comment: For API v2 with Essential access, use OAuth 2.0 with PKCE and the tweet.write scope.

Comment: @AndyPiper could you elaborate on that please? How exactly do you do that?

Comment: This will depend on the programming language you’re using.

Comment: I changed it from the setting actually. I found one tutorial. Forgot which one :DDD